# How do we determine when a modular Hamiltonian is local?

Tags: quantum-information, conformal-field-theory, quantum-gravity, density-operator, hamiltonian

I'm trying to deepen my understanding of [Von Neumann entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy) (out of interest in the [quantum Bekenstein bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound#Proof_in_quantum_field_theory)) by learning more about the [reduced density matrix (aka local density matrix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement#Reduced_density_matrices), which is given by the modular Hamiltonians (aka entanglement Hamiltonian). As I understand it, modular Hamiltonians are only known to be local (i.e. an integral of a local operator) under three specific situations.

1. When the state is the vacuum state in a half-plane (the only case where the modular Hamiltonian is given by the traditional Hamiltonian)
2. When the state is the vacuum state and is limited to a ball and the field theory is a CFT
3. When the state is the vacuum state and is limited to an arbitrary piece of a null plane

I could not, however, find any explanation for how or why these are the three known cases where it is local (and additionally why only the first one is given by the traditional Hamiltonian).

I'd appreciate any insight you could provide on this matter.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the definition of "local" here?

Comment: For the modular Hamiltonian, it means it is the integral of local operators. Local operators, in turn, are those with actions entirely dependent upon the value of a wavefunction and its derivatives at a single point.

Comment: What would be the conditions on an "explanation"? Do you require a proof, a hand-wavy argument, ... ? Some cases which come to mind: (1) States with a tensor network description (with some suitable properties). (2) Systems where a suitable version of the Bisognano-Wichmann-Thm. (as applied to the ent. spec.) applies.

Comment: Something in-between, please. Presenting equations as necessary and using proper terminology, but not getting bogged down in making an overly formal proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Current best answer I can give:

A modular Hamiltonian is local only when

$$\int_{\Sigma_{R}}\lambda(X)\mathcal{O}(X)\sqrt{g_{\Sigma_{R}}}dX^{d-1}=0$$

and

$$\int_{\Sigma_{R}}T^{\mu\nu}n_{\mu}\tau_{\nu}\sqrt{g_{\Sigma_{R}}}dX^{d-1}$$

has its integrand consisting entirely of elements that are themselves local.

For $d=3$, this is generically true for any CFT wherein any arbitrary interval is a line segment.[$^?$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/766501/how-do-we-determine-when-a-modular-hamiltonian-is-local)

I'll continue to try to refine this answer as I learn more. In particular, I believe I can refine this answer by learning more about geometric flows and modular flows.

---

---

I've just read [Flat-space limit of extremal curves](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.102.066002). The following are two excerpts from the paper.

> $\mathcal{H}_{A}$ is called the entanglement Hamiltonian or more commonly modular Hamiltonian in the literature and is the conserved charge of a geometric flow $k_{t}$, which is known as modular flow.

> In general, modular flows can only be identified with geometric flows generated by Killing vectors when the modular Hamiltonian is local. In three dimensions that any arbitrary interval in the boundary CFT is a line segment, the modular Hamiltonian is local. In higher dimensions, only spherical entangling regions will generate local modular Hamiltonians, so the interpretation of this modular Hamiltonian as generating a geometric flow, which is along the direction of a Killing vector, breaks down.

This sounds like it should answer my question, but I'm having difficulty parsing what exactly is being said since I lack an understanding of modular flows and geometric flows. Can anyone help clarify this?

---

I have also found [Modular Hamiltonian for holographic excited states](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.102.026021), which includes the following excerpt.

> A special case to be considered is whether the source $\lambda$
> does not depend on $\tau$. Thus, since the path ordering play no
> role, the (local) modular Hamiltonian on $W_{R}$ results
>
> $$K_{\lambda}\equiv2\pi(K_{0}+\mathcal{O}\cdot\lambda)$$
> $$=K_{0}+\int_{\Sigma_{R}}\lambda(X)\mathcal{O}(X)\sqrt{g_{\Sigma_{R}}}dX^{d-1},\tag{3.12}$$
>
> where $K_{0}$ can be expressed in terms of the energy-
> momentum tensor, the (timelike) Killing vector $\tau^{\mu}$ and
> the unit $n^{\mu}$ future pointing normal to $\Sigma_{R}$,
>
> $$K_{0}=\int_{\Sigma_{R}}T^{\mu\nu}n_{\mu}\tau_{\nu}\sqrt{g_{\Sigma_{R}}}dX^{d-1},\tag{3.13}$$

- $K_{0}$ ~ The modular Hamiltonian of the vacuum state
- $K_{\lambda}$ ~ The modular Hamiltonian of an excited state
- $T^{\mu\nu}$ ~ The stress-energy tensor
- $\tau$ ~ Represents the [Euclidean time](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2005APS..TSS.AB001A/abstract)
- $\lambda(X)$ ~ A function that "parametrizes the family of states"[$^?$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/766501/how-do-we-determine-when-a-modular-hamiltonian-is-local)
- $\mathcal{O}(X)$ ~ An operator of the CFT[$^?$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/766501/how-do-we-determine-when-a-modular-hamiltonian-is-local)
- $g$ ~ [I think] represents the metric tensor for the subscript manifold[$^?$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/766501/how-do-we-determine-when-a-modular-hamiltonian-is-local)
- $\Sigma_{R}$ ~ Represents the spacelike surface on the right Rindler wedge
- $n_{\mu}$ ~ A future-pointing unit vector normal to $\Sigma_{R}$